# How can I unlock a record in hibernate when exception occurs?

Tags: java, hibernate

I locked a record by using get(Classname.class, Serizelbea , LOCKOPTIONS) in Hibernate but an exception occurred, and I want to unlock this record. I have searched in the Internet but I haven't found any method to resolve this problem.

Please help me

Comment: Whether do you want to unlock programmatically or using query?

Comment: thanks. I want to unlock programmactically, because i must handle in code. can you give me a method of hibernate or similar to that

Comment: Enable auto commit in hibernate configuration, just refer documentation

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that an `evict` releases all locks that could exist on an object. If not, it would be a serious problem because Hibernate will keep a lock on a object it no longer knows.

And is you want to be able to access the record later you can do another `get` but without lock.

The only problem, is that it could be tedious if you want to test that the lock is **really** released.